# Может ли деепричастие, деепричастный оборот относиться к существительному?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

*Поднятие рук лёжа*.

*Поднятие рук лёжа на животе*.

Возможно ли употребление деепричастия и деепричастного оборота, которые относятся к существительному, а не к глаголу?

Answer (score 6):

Информация из "Русской корпусной грамматики":
[http://rusgram.ru/Деепричастие#_msocom_4](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#_msocom_4)

Деепричастия могут приобретать статус наречий.

*Он читает **лёжа*** – ‘он читает в определённой позе’ (наречие относится к глаголу).

А вот пример употребления наречия, восходящего к деепричастию, в спортивной терминологии: *прыжок с двумя боковыми винтами **согнувшись*** (относится к существительному).

Переход деепричастия в наречие характеризуется утратой синтаксических и морфологических признаков деепричастия и приобретением признаков, свойственных наречию, в том числе способности зависеть от существительного.

*Проезд **стоя** запрещён*.

Comment: Проезд стоя на голове запрещен.
Проезд утром на заре запрещен.
Я правильно понимаю, что здесь "стоя" и "утром" обстоятельства (наречия), а "на заре" и "на голове" дополнения к обстоятельствам? То есть бывший деепричастный оборот распадается на обстоятельство и дополнение к нему? Или же "утром" и "на заре" это два обстоятельства. А "стоя на голове"? - единственное, неделимое наречие(обстоятельство), а не обстоятельство + дополнение?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что насчёт деепричастного оборота?

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко, здравствуйте!  О каком деепричастном обороте идет речь? "Лежа на животе", "стоя на голове" в приведенных примерах утратили эти признаки и выступают в роли обстоятельства. Если Вы хотите получить ответ на вопрос "Может ли деепричастный оборот относиться к существительному?", то нужен пример. Я такого пока не могу найти и думаю, что "настоящий" дееприч. оборот должен относиться к глаголу. P. S. Спустя столько времени немного жаль видеть минус 15 баллов за "непринятие" ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий. Я правильно понимаю, что слова «лёжа» и «стоя» из сочетаний «лёжа на животе» и «стоя на голове» являются наречиями? И второй вопрос, уже заданный в комментариях пользователем user190920: «стоя на голове» — это цельное обстоятельство или обстоятельство и дополнение?

Comment: P.S. Не мог принять ваш ответ, так он не содержит объяснения по поводу деепричастного оборота, а только по поводу одиночного деепричастия.